# Using the total probability formula, find $Z$'s law.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

An insect lays eggs. The number of eggs laid is a random variable $X$ that follows a Poisson distribution of intensity $θ$. Each egg has a probability $p$ of hatching, independent of other eggs. Let $Z$ be the random variable that determines the number of eggs that hatched.

a) For $(k, n) ∈ \mathbb{N}^2$, calculate $P [Z = k | X = n]$.
b) Using the total probability formula, find $Z$'s law.

Hi, I've stuck in the part $b)$, I know what the formula means, but can't seem to find a way to use it for finding $Z$'s law

Can someone explain, how to use the formula in this case?

Comment: Did you use the fact that $Z|X \sim \text{Binomial}(X,p)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want $$P(Z=k) = \sum\limits_n P(Z=k|X=n)\cdot P(X=n)$$

Comment: So $P(Z = K) = [ \sum_{i=1}^{n} ({n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k})(e^{- θ} * \frac{θ^n}{n!})]$ right?