# Help simplyfing a sum

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation

Hi I was working on a [Probability problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3975585/using-the-total-probability-formula-find-zs-law/3975592#3975592)  and got as result this expression

$$P(Z = k) = \sum\limits_n \left({n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\right)\left(e^{- θ} * \frac{θ^n}{n!}\right)$$

And now I'm trying to simplify the expresion, but so far I only achieved this:

$$\sum\limits_n \left({n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\right)\left(e^{- θ} * \frac{θ^n}{n!}\right) $$

$$=\sum\limits_n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}e^{- θ}θ^n  $$

$$=\frac{p^{k}e^{-θ}}{k!}\sum\limits_n  \frac{(1-p)^{n-k}θ^n}{(n-k)!} $$

But now I'm at this point and I don't what else to do to simplify. Can someone help me?

Comment: I am confused because the sum is over an index $i$, yet the $i$ variable appears nowhere.  As written, the sum should disappear and you just multiply everything by $n$.

Comment: These probabilities don’t add up to $1$.

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong Tex Command

Comment: I modify the question

Comment: I read this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211914/a-binomial-multiplied-by-a-poisson/211928) but I'm still confused

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly your sum is over $n\geq k$, so
$$\frac{p^ke^{-\theta}}{k!}\sum_{n\geq k}\frac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\theta^n=\frac{p^ke^{-\theta}}{k!}\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{(1-p)^m}{m!}\theta^{m+k}=\frac{p^ke^{-\theta}}{k!}\cdot\theta^k\cdot e^{(1-p)\theta}$$
i.e. $Z\sim\operatorname{Po}(p\theta)$.